# Azure DevOps : excluding updates to yaml pipeline files from triggering those same pipelines?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

Somehow I'm not getting how I can exclude updates yaml pipelines from trigger the pipelines themselves. I have tried some wildcards as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/file-matching-patterns?view=azure-devops) both in the include item (with the ! operator) or in the exclude item and nothing worked. I've added the plain pipeline names with no wildcards in the excluded item and again it did not work. The yaml files sit in the root of my repository (no containing folder).

These don't work

```
trigger:
    branches:
        include:
        - MyBranch
    paths:
        exclude:
        - "*.yml"
        - "**/*.yml"
```

Clearly adding the full name of the pipeline works but you can't always edit exisitng yaml files each and every time you add a new one

Comment: Can you provide the trigger portion of the yaml here

Comment: Edited my initial question, also see my answer below. It seems that using the same wildcards with the not operator in the include section is effective

Answer (score 0):

If you don’t want to trigger the pipeline when updating `azure-pipelines.yml` file, you can set the following trigger:

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - master
  paths:
    exclude:
    - /azure-pipelines.yml
```

Comment: That also works but intellisense is misleading, it underlines that path, the staring slash seems to lead it to expect some reg ex expression

Comment: Using this approach would not be effective, you can't go edit all yaml files each an every time you add a new one to the monitored branches

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused, with the following syntax CI pipelines **are not triggered** when updating *.yml files

```
trigger:
    branches:
        include:
        - MyBranch
    paths:
        include:
          - '!**/*.yml'
```

while with the following one (which as I understand it should mean the same thing as the above one) pipelines **keep being triggered** when updating any *.yml file

```
trigger:
    branches:
        include:
        - MyBranch
    paths:
        exclude:
          - "**/*.yml"
```

What am I not getting?

Comment: ok, so this does not really work as CI pipelines are not getting triggered now even when non-yaml files are being updated

Comment: I suppose the only viable solution is to place pipelines in a folder and exclude that folder

Comment: Thanks for sharing your answer here, would you please accept your answer as the answer? So it would be helpful for other members who get the same issue to find the solution easily. Have a nice day:)